# Hign traffic but low Alexa Rank

Tags: google-analytics, ranking, alexa

I have a website for more than one year (it's a blog with .com domain).

I track my visitors using Google Analytics and I mention that I have an average of 7000 unique visitors/day. The whole year since my blog is online I had over 2.000.000 unique visitors but my Alexa.com Rank is 25.000.000

How is it possible?

Note that some of my visitors came from PTC websites or traffic exchanges.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa traffic records and ranking are based on the data collected by users visiting a site using their toolbar or people with alexa widget. This is something like their business model. They want to track data so they ask you to make your own custom toolbar and ask your user to install it are place a widget on your site.

Although their ranking is becoming better and better but it is still 0 for developers who have not considered to optimize their site for Alexa Ranking.

Please note a few tips:

1. Install their toolbar for FireFox or extension for chrome and browse
   your site.
2. Place a widget on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa ranks being improved by the Widget is a myth. It's not a pixel!

Alexa ranks are based on:

- Reports from a Toolbar (Not popular outside of the US)
- Reports from partnered browser extensions (pays for some free extensions data)
- Paid for tracking javascript ($10 a month)
- A 3 month average of your history (Updated Weekly)

You won't show up if you have insignificant traffic coming from users browsers. iFrames can mess with tracking as well - because of the way it's reported. There's also a rumour that they use their own datacenter traffic to make estimates as well - and AWS being as large as it is, that's a believable alternative.